# Where can I find a log-file for the ADB process that Android Studio launches?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Question:

a)  Is there somewhere I can find ADB logs for the instance of ADB that Android Studio launches, so I can see any ADB errors?  (Problem being that ADB is crashing on me)

-- OR --

b)  Is there a way to launch ADB from the command-line, and have Android Studio connect to my instance of ADB, so I can watch the output of ADB for errors?

My environment is:

- Windows 11
- Android Studio Electric Eel patch 2
- ADB.EXE version 34.0.1-9680074

Edit 3:
The man page for ADB (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/adb/+/refs/heads/master/docs/user/adb.1.md) has a section titled "Environment Variables", where it talks about a variable named ADB_TRACE:  "Comma-separated list of debug info to log: all, adb, sockets, packets, rwx, usb, sync, sysdeps, transport, jdwp".  But again, where does this log information go in Windows?  It doesn't seem to go to stdout/stderr.

Edit:
The reason I want to do this is because I'm trying to troubleshoot the fact that ADB crashes every 1-2 minutes, which keeps popping up the message on my Android phone to allow USB debugging.  I know ADB is crashing because I can literally watch the ADB process in Windows Task Manager and it keeps stopping and restarting every couple minutes.  If I leave it there for 20 minutes, then there are 10-20 stacked popups all asking "Do you want to allow USB debugging", and I have to dismiss them all individually.

Edit 2:
When ADB stops, I know the reason is NOT because "I'm just not using ADB".  I'm in the middle of an Android debug session, and the ADB process will spontaneously stop, and restart, which leads to the message on my phone "Do you want to Allow USB debugging".  And the allow-USB popup appears multiple times, once for each time ADB starts and stops.  I'm not looking for someone to troubleshoot ADB or troubleshoot Android Studio for me.  I just want to know how I can get some logs to ADB so I can troubleshoot myself.

Comment: May be adb is not crashing but there are two adb installations "fighting" which one is active. Multiple adb installations with different versions are a common problem. When looking at the adb processes you should also check the command/path of the executable if it is the same or if it changes.

Comment: I actually thought of that, but the problem is that the ADB processes show up and disappear within seconds, so there’s no time to right-click the process in the task manager and get the properties.  Is there some other way to check the command/path of a Windows executable that is only running for a few seconds?

Comment: If the new instance directly closes then it is not a problem of two conflicting adb versions. Open a shell and execute the two commands `adb kill-server`and `adb start-server` and check their output or error message(s).

Comment: are you sure that this is what's going on?  Your usb driver could be crashing.  ADB only activates when it's being used.  It doesn't run constantly.  I would verify you don't have something trying to use the same port though, such as pda.net, which also tries to connect to your phone.

Comment: @John Lord No, I'm not sure exactly what is going on.  That's why the question is:  How can I look at some log files to ADB, so I can figure out what's going on.  All I know for sure is that the ADB process is stopping and restarting all the time.  And yes ADB stops while I'm in the middle of trying to use it with Android Studio debugging session, so the problem isn't that I'm just not using ADB.

Comment: @Robert I tried using "adb kill-server" and then "adb start-server".  This does indeed restart ADB from the command-line, but I don't get any useful output to stdout/stderr in the command-line window.  So the mystery remains, how to get some logs for the ADB process?

Comment: did you check logcat in android studio?

Comment: @John Lord Of course.  Logcat in Android Studio just shows "PROCESS ENDED (PID)" when ADB crashes.  No explanation or error.  If I just let my phone sit there while connected, ADB stops (and restarts) periodically.  If I try to use ADB by doing a debugging session with my app in Android Studio, the same thing happens-- at random intervals ADB will simply stop inexplicably mid-testing.  This makes it impossible to get any real development work done.  I'm beginning to believe that meaningful logs about ADB simply don't exist.  Which seems pretty odd, but I've seen stranger things...

Comment: then it's almost certainly your phone is disconnecting.  ADB isn't showing any errors.  Switch to a different usb port for starters.  Also try a different cable.    And i don't mean a port on the same controller.  You could be overloading that port.  If you're plugged into the front of your case, plug into the back instead, or vice versa.

Comment: @John Lord All of that was tried long ago.  Including trying multiple phones.  All phones and all USB ports and all USB cables do the same thing.  I eventually re-installed Windows and reloaded my whole machine, and the problem disappeared.  I appreciate the help though.  I still feel like there should be a log somewhere, but what do I know :)

Comment: in general windows itself only logs exceptions i believe.  If it was closing for some other reason, shrug, i wouldn't know why.